# No Data in Firebase analytics dashboard for Unity in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I integrated firebase analytics into unity and followed all the steps mentioned in the firebase guide. I received the analytics from the unity stream.
**the problem** is that when I integrate unity in android, the analytics no longer appear.